# JQuery/AJAX - How To? Better Outcome?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

DataPull.php:

```
    CASE "CityList":
        echo "<select style='width:132px;height:243px;' size='17' id='CityListA' name='CityListA' onChange='SubCityList(this.value);'>";
        $result = $db-> query("SELECT region_id,region_name FROM dwrel_region ORDER BY region_name");
        while ($row = $db-> fetch_assoc($result)){
            echo "<option value='".$row["region_id"]."'>".$row["region_name"]."</option> \n";
        }
        echo "</select>";
        break;
```

JavaScript:

```
function CityList(){
    try{var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();}catch (e){try{xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");}catch (e){try{xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");}catch (e){return false;}}}
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){getEl("CityList").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;}}
    eMsg = "DataPull.php?get=CityList";
    xmlhttp.open("GET",eMsg);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

It works just fine for me.  Was reading around JQuery/AJAX and surprised you could do it via $(function(){}); part.. but I don't or can't begin to understand where and how to put it together "as is" with the code I have above.  Hopefully someone out there is kind enough to guide me to the right direction using AJAX, pulling and output results.

Was trying to understand how to be able to use this, even reading mentioned the use of JSON? (I think) or data "as is", something.. Oh I don't know.. Anyways, hopefully someone could help me put this together and then I could understand it even better.

Thanks!

**EDIT:**
After weeks from this post, learned a new way to do this:
in CSS:

```
.LoaderIcon {width:100%;height:100%;background:url('./images/Loading.gif') no-repeat center center;}
```

in JQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    beforeSend: function(){ $('#SOMEID').addClass('LoaderIcon'); },
    url: "SOME PARAMETER",
    success:function(data){
        $('#SOMEID').removeClass('LoaderIcon');
        $('#SOMEID').html(data)
    }
```

This has been working like charm for me, hopefully it would benefit others :)
    });

Comment: So do you want to convert above code to equivalent jQuery?

Comment: yes that's the idea, I just can't begin how to "convert" into JQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
function CityList(){
 $("#YOUR_SPINNING_DIV_ID").html('<img src="PATH_TO_SPINNINGANIM_GIF"');
 $.ajax({
url: "DataPull.php?get=CityList",
success: function(data ){
  $("#CityList").html(data );
$("#YOUR_SPINNING_DIV_ID").html("");
 }
});
 }
```

and then call this function on any event that you are observing like button clicks or window onload. If you are doing it on windown onload then Jquery equivalient will be

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

 $.ajax({
url: "DataPull.php?get=CityList",
success: function(data ){
  $("#CityList").html(data );
 }
});
 )};
```

Comment: is that gonna pull RAW data? or based on what I requested in Datapull.php?

Comment: It will pull whatever you ECHO in your switch case "CityList". I mean you can always use JSON but your login at client side will need to change than. Above code will accept HTML so thats what (html) is expected in return

Comment: ahh gotcha, now in that regard, I had a "spinning 'loading'" icon when pulling data, where would i place that in there?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this in your `jQuery(document).ready()`

```
$.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    url:'DataPull.php',
    data:'get=CityList',
    success:function(msg){
        alert('Success!\n\n+'+msg);
    },
    error:function(msg){
        alert('Error!\n\n'+msg);
    }
});
```

Where `msg` is the `echo` from the given PHP file. [Read more about it on the jQuery website](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).